# MySql insert syntax error

Tags: mysql

Sry but I just don't understand what is wrong in my syntext, can you help me?

```
"insert into users2(id,first_name,last_name,full_name,email,password,validation_key) ('1a9a14aa-cc87-4365-ab6a-2501b4e70d06','Name','Pass','NamePass','koko@lolol.com','OYJBYZw9IW0gLbkKSTXJeKTBYcRaNw0=','054eb292-0b9f-4219-830d-fadd1a8af7ad')"
```

Comment: Please, don't tell us the error message, it would spoil all the fun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO users2 (id, first_name, last_name, full_name, email, password, validation_key) 
VALUES ('1a9a14aa-cc87-4365-ab6a-2501b4e70d06','Name','Pass','NamePass','koko@lolol.com','OYJBYZw9IW0gLbkKSTXJeKTBYcRaNw0=','054eb292-0b9f-4219-830d-fadd1a8af7ad')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing [`VALUES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO users2
            (id,
             first_name,
             last_name,
             full_name,
             email,
             password,
             validation_key)
VALUES      ('1a9a14aa-cc87-4365-ab6a-2501b4e70d06',
             'Ilya',
             'Gazman',
             'IlyaGazman',
             'koko@lolol.com',
             'OYJBYZw9IW0gLbkKSTXJeKTBYcRaNw0=',
             '054eb292-0b9f-4219-830d-fadd1a8af7ad')
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `values` before the values.